# jQuery append problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a problem with `append()` working in IE but not in FF. I append text to a content in text area. if I load textarea with text and then delete a few chars, and then try to append -- it does not work. Is there an alternative to it?

Comment: How is it that you have asked 74 questions, and still don't know that with no code, you might as well not ask at all?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong.... though my powers are not string (strong :P :D) enough to predict what. Could you post your code to make it easier for us?

Comment: @Felix, "my powers are not string enough", nice unintentional pun :)

Comment: I think its awesome I wouldn't correct it.

Comment: @davin: That could be a nice programmer slogan: *Are you really string enough to do...?* or *How string are **you**?*

Comment: @Felix, yeah, although IMO it should be used in the context of string- or string-like-related topics only.

Comment: Please see my comment below the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with a `textarea`, you should be using `.val()` to set its value instead of `.append()`.

```
$('textarea').val( function( i, val ) { return val + "new text"; } );
```

Comment: @ElGuapo: Patrick is one of our Masters. It is difficult to trick him. May the Force be with you both!

Comment: Normally I post the code. In this case I checked my code many times and was looking for an insight of this caliber. The problem is not my code but the wrong choice of code for TEXTAREA. Thanks @patrick dw!

Comment: @Felix, @ElGuapo: You're *far* too kind. :o)